# PHP: Showing How Long Ago A File Was Modified

Tags: php, time

I am using the following code to show how long ago a file was last modified

```
echo gmdate("d\d H\h i\m s\s", time()-filemtime(FILENAME));
```

This will result in something like `00d 00h 15m 28s` to show a file was last modified 15m ago.

I am trying to limit how much time I can show if it will just be zeros. I.e. instead of `00d 00h 15m 28s` I want it to just show `15m 28s`.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Just convert the time to regular time

Comment: I'd use `\DateTime()` tho, easier to manage and the code doesn't look like 1998.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and use the [setTimestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php) method to set the timestamp from [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php).

For example:

```
<?php
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTimeFile = new DateTime();
$dateTimeFile->setTimestamp(filemtime(FILENAME));
$interval = $dateTime->diff($dateTimeFile);
echo rtrim(
    sprintf(
        "%s%s%s%s",
        $interval->d > 0 ? $interval->d . "d " : "",
        $interval->h > 0 ? $interval->h . "h " : "",
        $interval->i > 0 ? $interval->i . "m " : "",
        $interval->s > 0 ? $interval->s . "s " : ""
    )
);
```

Comment: I like this solution since it is easy to understand and does not require arithmetic and a bunch of if statements

Answer (score 3):

It's not really what you want...

I'm currently using this:

```
define('MINUTE_IN_SECONDS', 60);
define('HOUR_IN_SECONDS', 60 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS);
define('DAY_IN_SECONDS', 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS);
define('WEEK_IN_SECONDS', 7 * DAY_IN_SECONDS);
define('YEAR_IN_SECONDS', 365 * DAY_IN_SECONDS);

function humanTimeDifference($from, $to = '') {
    if ( empty( $to ) )
        $to = time();
    $diff = (int) abs( $to - $from );
    if ( $diff < HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) {
        $mins = round( $diff / MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( $mins <= 1 )
            $mins = 1;
        $since = sprintf( _n( '%s minute', '%s minutes', $mins ), $mins );
    } elseif ( $diff < DAY_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) {
        $hours = round( $diff / HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( $hours <= 1 )
            $hours = 1;
        $since = sprintf( _n( '%s hour', '%s hours', $hours ), $hours );
    } elseif ( $diff < WEEK_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= DAY_IN_SECONDS ) {
        $days = round( $diff / DAY_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( $days <= 1 )
            $days = 1;
        $since = sprintf( _n( '%s day', '%s days', $days ), $days );
    } elseif ( $diff < 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= WEEK_IN_SECONDS ) {
        $weeks = round( $diff / WEEK_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( $weeks <= 1 )
            $weeks = 1;
        $since = sprintf( _n( '%s week', '%s weeks', $weeks ), $weeks );
    } elseif ( $diff < YEAR_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ) {
        $months = round( $diff / ( 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ) );
        if ( $months <= 1 )
            $months = 1;
        $since = sprintf( _n( '%s month', '%s months', $months ), $months );
    } elseif ( $diff >= YEAR_IN_SECONDS ) {
        $years = round( $diff / YEAR_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( $years <= 1 )
            $years = 1;
        $since = sprintf( _n( '%s year', '%s years', $years ), $years );
    }
    return $since;
}

function _n($single, $plural, $number) {
    if($number > 1) {
        return $plural;
    } else {
        return $single;
    }
}
```

I just took it from my [GitHub project](https://github.com/jankal/MomentTime)