# PHP Format Datetime to Not Have Zeros

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I have the following query to display a formatted `datetime` object

```
echo $interval->format("%hh %im %ss");
```

which will return time as something like `0h 5m 12s` or `3h 15m 2s`

Is there a way to elegantly return the datetime to not have 0s in the front? I.e. instead of `0h 0m 3s`, it would just display `3s`

Comment: try `trim(str_replace(array('0h','0m'),'',$formatresult))`, if the class cant do it

Comment: just a simple one   ;)

Comment: will not really work for `1h 0m 3s`  result is then `1h  3s`, dont thing you want that

Comment: try `ltrim($formatresult,' 0h 0m ');`  thing that should work better

Comment: I could always just do `ltrim($formatresult,' 0h 0m ');` and then `ltrim($formatresult,' 0h ');`

Comment: once `ltrim($formatresult,' 0h 0m ');` is ok,  last bug wolud be here `0h 0m 0s`  result `s`  ;)

Comment: With my code, it will never be `0h 0m 0s`. I posted another solution that will create the string in the format I want instead of just trimming the `0`s out of it

Comment: One of the million-way-to-rome PHP Solutions ;) was just a try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution from one of my [past questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100167/2893712) that uses `rtrim`, `sprintf`, and comparisons for `$interval`.

```
    $interval = $future_date->diff($now);
    $time_until = rtrim(sprintf("%s%s%s",
        $interval->h > 0 ? $interval->h . "h " : "",
        $interval->i > 0 ? $interval->i . "m " : "",
        $interval->s > 0 ? $interval->s . "s " : ""
        )
    );
```

If the time is `> 0`, then it will print the time. Otherwise, it will just be left blank

Comment: *"I found a solution"* - can you post the source to credit the author. Or by found, do you mean with trial/error on your own, or?

Comment: It was actually from another one of my other questions but the solutions code had this in it.

Comment: will not really work for `1h 0m 3s` result is then `1h 3s` instead of `1h 0m 3s` ;) Where is rome?